# How much data can a phone's USB transfer per second?

Tags: data-driven

I'm conceiving a game that relies heavely on transfer speed from pc to phone. From USB it seems to be faster than wi-fi. But i can't get precise numbers on the net, everywhere tells me a diferente story.
Does anybody know how much data can i transfer from pc to phone via USB per second?

Comment: 12 parsecs of data. More seriously, it depends on if it's USB 2 or 3, speed of the PC storage, speed of the phone storage, lots of small transfers or few large transfers, and so on. There is no single figure for this.

Comment: Why ask a game developer this? As you've probably noticed, most games don't rely on heavy USB data transfers between phone and PC during play, so this isn't something a typical game developer would be likely to have more experience with than, say, a hardware engineer. Just because you're using something in a game does not necessarily make it a game development question. This looks to me like something the Engineering StackExchange might be better-suited to answer, but be sure to check their help center first to verify that it's on topic for them, and be specific about models/versions.

Comment: Or, if you want to take advantage of our expertise here, ask about the game parts. What mechanic or player-facing gameplay does this USB activity drive? Maybe we can suggest ways to achieve that target player experience that won't demand pushing the theoretical limits of USB bandwidth or latency, depending on what forms of "speed" are relevant to your gameplay.